# Python - Iterations of character replacements

Tags: python, string, iteration

I apologize if this has been answered previously - I wasn't entirely sure how to explain/search for this so I couldn't find anything existing.

I'm going through a large list of strings and trying to find matches in another data set. The input data set is space separated, and the existing data set uses an inconsistent combination of underscores and camel-case.

I'm looking for a clean way to iterate across all possibilities of these combinations. 
The simplest case is this:

Input: "Variant Type"

Desired Output: "Variant_Type", "VariantType"

I had been accomplishing this 2-word case by searching twice:

```
x = input.replace(' ','_')
# Search 
x = x.replace('_','')
# Search again
```

But now that I'm realizing there are a lot of longer strings like:

Input: "Timeline Integration Enabled"

Desired output:

"Timeline_Integration_Enabled", "TimelineIntegration_Enabled", "Timeline_IntegrationEnabled", "TimelineIntegrationEnabled"

Is there a clever, Pythonic way to accomplish this?

Note: I know I could use something like difflib.get_close_matches(), but I was hoping to do that as a last pass over the data, prompting the user to make decisions on any fields that weren't clear.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: This is the best and simplest way you can achieve it.

Comment: How could it be if user inputs like "Timeline integration enabled"? Will it be changed first letter to capital then append or just like  "Timeline_integration_enabled"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def iterate_replacements(input_data):
    if " " in input_data:
        yield from iterate_replacements(input_data.replace(" ", "", 1))
        yield from iterate_replacements(input_data.replace(" ", "_", 1))
    else:
        yield input_data

for s in iterate_replacements("Timeline Integration Enabled"):
    print(s)
```

Or, for 2.7, which doesn't support `yield from`:

```
def iterate_replacements(input_data):
    if " " in input_data:
        for x in iterate_replacements(input_data.replace(" ", "", 1)): yield x
        for x in iterate_replacements(input_data.replace(" ", "_", 1)): yield x
    else:
        yield input_data

for s in iterate_replacements("Timeline Integration Enabled"):
    print(s)
```

Result:

```
TimelineIntegrationEnabled
TimelineIntegration_Enabled
Timeline_IntegrationEnabled
Timeline_Integration_Enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can connect strings together although the way you did was simple.Using Django's slugify.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
print(slugify("Variant Type"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you are simply trying to remove underscores and spaces.

If you get a match for Timeline_Integration you will also get a match for TimelineIntegration, so I am a little confused as to why you want every permutation possible for replacing spaces with '_' or ''.

Example:  searching "Timeline Integration Method":

Searching for "Timeline_Integration":

Why not just replace _ in the input strings for the search as well as the searched text.  This keeps consistency.  Or if you want to be case sensitive just replace '_' with ' '.

Unless I am completely misunderstanding the goal, I believe a possible solution would be to just completely remove the first search and do something like this:

Solutions:

## space insensitive

search_string = ''.join([x for x in search_string if x != ' ' and x!= '_'])
to_be_searched_string = ''.join([x for x in to_be_searched_string if x != ' ' and x!= '_'])

## space sensitive

search_string = ''.join([x for x in search_string if x != ' ' else '_'])
to_be_searched_string = ''.join([x for x in to_be_searched_string if x !=' ' else '_'])